# GCP App Engine w/Django: big pandas load in views is causing failure

Tags: django, google-app-engine

One of my page views in GCP App Engine (standard) is failing to load.

[image]

I've determined that the issue occurs when Django temporarily loads a large pandas dataframe from cache (30mb). This is necessary in order for my charts to grab a *subset* of the data for charts before page rendering (it is not being injected into the html at all).

```
def myView(request):
    baseTable = cache.get("somecachekey") #issue is here
    chartDiv = makeChart(baseTable)
    return render(request, template_name = 'myView.html', context = {'chart' : chartDiv})
```

Interestingly, **there are no server errors**. The logs seem fine. Also, **this view works successfully when I am locally hosting Django on my laptop**. I suppose there is some sort of timeout issue, but the error occurs within a couple seconds so I am not sure if that is the cause. Any advice here?

Answer (score 0):

After rerunning the view a few times I eventually got a warning about the memory limit. It recommended I set a higher instance class. I did that in the app.yaml file to F4 and it worked!